# Getting captions from images uploaded to Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress, image, attachment, caption

I've uploaded some images to a post, added captions to them in the "uploaded to this post" view.

When accessing them with get_children() the captions are nowhere to be found. Can't find them in the database (wp_postmeta), neither through the post array (as excerpt or title), wp_get_attachment_metadata(), get_post_meta() or get_post_custom().

When I reload the post in the admin interface and revisit the add media interface the saved captions are apparently saved as they're still shown when filtering with  "uploaded to this post."  However not when filtered with "all media items," or viewed through the media menu.

Any ideas where this data is stored, and a builtin way to access it?

```
$images =& get_children( array (
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));                                             

print_r($images);
if (count($images) <= 1) {
    the_post_thumbnail('portfolio-1column', array('alt' => get_the_title(), 'class' => 'shadow'));
} 
else 
{
?>
    <ul class="bxslider" id="bxslider_article">
<?php                  
    $i=0;
    foreach ($images as $image_id => $image) {
        $img_file = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'portfolio-1column');
?>
    <li>
    <img src="<?php echo $img_file[0]; ?>" title="pic<?php echo $i; ?>" /></li>
<?php
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </ul>
<?php
    }

                                                    }
```

This is what I get:

```
Array ( 
[842] => WP_Post Object ( 
    [ID] => 842 [post_author] => 1 
    [post_date] => 2014-07-16 09:07:13 
    [post_date_gmt] => 2014-07-16 07:07:13 
    [post_content] => 
        [post_title] => 20140525_184556(2) 
        [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => inherit 
            [comment_status] => closed 
            [ping_status] => closed 
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => 20140525_1845562-2 
            [to_ping] => 
                [pinged] => 
                [post_modified] => 2014-07-16 09:07:13 
                [post_modified_gmt] => 2014-07-16 07:07:13 
                [post_content_filtered] => 
                    [post_parent] => 646 
                    [guid] => http://pal.localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/20140525_18455621.jpg 
                    [menu_order] => 0 
                    [post_type] => attachment 
                    [post_mime_type] => image/jpeg 
                    [comment_count] => 0 
                    [filter] => raw ) 
[843] [...] ) )
```

Comment: <?php echo $post->post_excerpt; ?> <- GOOGLED IT

Comment: As I said, "neither through the post array (as excerpt or title)" - $post->post_excerpt is empty

Comment: you said as `excerpt` - showing your code is better as `post_excerpt` is different to `excerpt`. Do a print_r on $post to check that you have the right post. `$img = get_post( get_post_thumbnail_id() );` should also be tried and then do `$img->post_excerpt`.

Comment: Added code sample now. Sorry. I know I have the right post ID, and the children are the right items too.

Comment: my only suggestion is that this is a custom post type and excerpt is not being returned by the function that builds the array. The best way to track this down would be to look at the php file that creates the post and see if it is being created with a custom name. The other thing to try is to search the database for a VALUE that you know is there (not for post_excerpt but for the actually post in the value field) - perhaps it is being saved as something obscure!